# effect on changing background

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function changecolors() {
  x = 1;
  setInterval(change, 7000);
}
```

And second function is this one:

```
function change() {
  if(x == 1) {
    document.getElementById('right').style.background='url(images/1.png)'
  }
}
```

How can I apply any effect on background change ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `any effect on background change`?

Comment: @gongzhitaao What do you mean by "Where is the `jquery`"?

Comment: Take the concept from here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/ so you can animate opacity etc

Comment: http://jls.lt/vaidus/ - now background changes without any effects... i want to applay effect like slide or smth..

Comment: @ImranBughio this Q used to have an `jquery` tag

Comment: the effect you linked is on the div and not the background image

Comment: @Olumide it's on body <body onLoad="changecolors()" style="background-color:#B5B4AA;">

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for an animation effect when background image appears.

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ddg4u/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="right">
    <div id="right-bg"></div> // Note an extra div is being used to animate background using opacity of this div.
    <p>Hello!!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#right {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    Padding: 25px;
}
#right-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function changecolors() {
    x = 1;
    setInterval(change, 7000);
}

function change() {
    if (x == 1) {
        document.getElementById('right-bg').style.background = 'url(http://placehold.it/100x100)';
        document.getElementById('right-bg').style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
changecolors();
```